# XML data via API to Land in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase, flume, apache-storm

We are receiving huge amounts of XML data via API. In-order to handle this large data set, we were planning to do it in Hadoop.

Needed your help in understanding how to efficiently bring the data to Hadoop. What are the tools available ? Is there a possibility of bringing this data real-time ?

Please provide your inputs.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Oh..looks like you are already aware of Flume :)

Comment: I was looking for examples for bringing XML data into hadoop using Flume. (Assume some API)

Comment: I'm afraid, I am not aware of any such example. See if this helps : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14275153/write-a-custom-httpsource-handler-for-flume-ng

Comment: Currently where you are getting this data, Is there any specific location where data gets store and further you want to process on Hadoop or You want to directly load your XML data on HDFS.Please specify. We have also similar use case.

Comment: We are getting this data from external API outside of our company firewall. We want to connect to the API and land the XML data into HDFS. What would be the best way to accomplish the same ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are receiving **huge** amounts of data, the appropriate way, IMHO, would be to use some aggregation tool like [Flume](http://flume.apache.org/). Flume is a distributed, reliable, and available service for efficiently collecting, aggregating, and moving large amounts of data into your Hadoop cluster from different types of sources.

You can easily write custom sources based on your needs to collect the data. You might fins this [link](https://github.com/cloudera/cdh-twitter-example) helpful to get started. It presents a custom Flume source designed to connect to the Twitter Streaming API and ingest tweets in a raw JSON format into HDFS. You could try something similar for your xml data.

You might also wanna have a look at [Apache Chukwa](http://incubator.apache.org/chukwa/) which does the same thing.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Flume, Scribe & Chukwa are the tools that can accomplish the above task. However Flume is most popularly used tool of all the three. Flume has strong Reliability and Failover techniques available. As well Flume has commercial support available from Cloudera while the other two does not have.

Comment: This is an external API which is outside of our company's firewall. So In-order to extract the XML file from the API on a daily basis using Flume, what are the things that needs to be done ? Should Flume agent be installed on the external API provider site as well? what will be the configuration ?

Answer (score 0):

If your only objective is for the data to land in HDFS, you can keep writing the XML responses to disk following some convention such as data-2013-08-05-01.xml and write a daily (or hourly cron) to import the XML data in HDFS. Running Flume will be overkill if you don't need streaming capabilities. From your question, it is not immediately obvious why you need Hadoop? Do you need to run MR jobs?

Answer (score 0):

You want to put the data into Avro or your choice of protocol buffer for processing.  Once you have a buffer to match the format of the text the hadoop ecosystem is of much better help in processing the structured data.

Hadoop originally was found most useful for taking one line entries of log files and structuring / processing the data from their.  XML is already structured and requires more processing power to get it into a hadoop friendly format.

A more basic solution would be to chunking the xml data and process using [Wukong](https://github.com/infochimps-labs/wukong) (Ruby streaming) or a python alternative.  Since your network bound by the 3rd party api a streaming solution might be more flexible and just as fast in the end for your needs.